# How to create a form where there is an input file for uploading the cover and another for multiple photos?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to create a form where I have an input file to send the cover to a photo album, and a second input file where I select several photos, I've done a lot of research, but I couldn't find an example. The HTML would be this template below:

```css
form{
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

form button{
  background-color: crimson;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
form input[type="text"]{
  padding: 7px 10px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Select album cover</label>
  <input type="file" name="cover">
  <label>Select photos</label>
  <input type="file" name="photos">
  <input type="text" name="nameAlbum" placeholder="Photo album name"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I need a model with upload in php PDO and mysql with this structure above, with a single upload I was able to do it, but unfortunately not with two. I thank you for your help.

Comment: Why, what went wrong? The process is similar for two as for one. Post your attempt and explain the specific problem, we're not going to rewrite the whole thing for you. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not sure where to start, have a look at [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see what they offer. They come in a variety of styles, from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to very feature complete like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). Most include some kind of login mechanism out of the box so you won't have to write your own. They also show you how to organize your code so you don't end up with a confusing stew of PHP, HTML, CSS and SQL that is impossible to maintain or iterate on.

Comment: If you want **multiple** photos in that photo file field -- Just add `multiple` to the input:  `<input type="file" name="photos" multiple>`

Comment: Also to @ADyson's point ..  It should be the same for both.  Did you `print_r($_FILES);` --  You should see everything you need in that output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['photos']);
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (id, name) VALUES(?,?)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['photos'][$i];
    $target_file = 'uploads/'.$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$target_file);
    $statement->execute(array($filename,$target_file));
}
```

change the input element to:

```
<input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>
```

Comment: How can I have this multiple upload, and one more upload with the cover option?

Comment: @AndréRodrigues -- I am afraid to say, if you don't understand Shankar's basic answer,  in addition to the comments in your post, you may be out of your depth, and a basic tutorial on PHP may be in order.

Comment: @AndréRodrigues this just shows you how to handle multiple uploads from the photos input. If you want to have more code to handle the cover upload then just add some standard upload-handling code for that as well, in the same script. It's unclear what is stopping you from doing that - in your question you indicated you had already achieved code to handle one upload